# PHP mysql delete entry from all table

Tags: php, mysql

- I have 85 tables in my database (Staff, access, training, notifications etc...)
- All the table have one field common field staff_id. m facing problem to remove unwanted records
- Is there any way I can delete record from 85 tables where staff id = xyz

Comment: Do your tables have referential integrity because you defined all your foreign keys?

Comment: Yup, All the tables have referential integrity and all the tables are connected via staff_id....

Comment: if you have proper relationships between the tables, try cascading delete: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20cascading%20delete

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
//Loop through all tables 
set_time_limit(0);
$res = mysqli_query($db,"SHOW TABLES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {    
    $table = $row[0];
    //Add created_at column if not exist, else alter the field
    $response = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE staff_id = xyz");

    if ($response)
        echo "Data deleted from " . $table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. You have join all the tables as follows. Here I joined only above given tables. Also consider the  foreign key constraints before delete records.

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3, t4 FROM
  staff as t1
  INNER JOIN  access as t2 on t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id
  INNER JOIN  training as t3 on t1.staff_id=t3.staff_id
  INNER JOIN  notifications as t4 on t1.staff_id=t4.staff_id
  WHERE  t1.staff_id=xyz;
```

Unless try as this:

```
$tables = array("staff", "access", "training", "notifications");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE staff_id=xyz";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Comment: This way i have to create t1,t2,t3...... upto 85 and m still continue to adding new tables....

Comment: Ok. Go on. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

do you mean like this?

```
DELETE FROM `entries` WHERE staff_id="spiderman"
```